# Only display a band when the document is printed

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

Is there a built-in parameter in *iReport/JasperReports Server* that will allow me to hide a band when a report is displayed in *JasperReports Server*, but display the band when the report is printed? I don't want to display my report footers when the user is viewing reports on-screen in *JasperReports Server*.

Comment: You can add a report parameter and use the band's "Print When Expression". You can initialize this parameter from Java code when you print report or from the JR Server.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That sounds exactly like what I want to do. Do you know how I can initialize the parameter when printed?

Comment: Which way are you using for printing the report (Java code or Print button in application, for example in MS Word)?

Comment: We are printing from within the browser, or if the document is exported to Word or Adobe Acrobat, from there.

Comment: I think that it will be easier to pass parameter from the JR Server in this case